# Write content of NSURL to an array

Tags: ios, uisplitview

I have a program that retrieves data from a link and i write it out to the Log like this.

```
NSURL *getURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"link.php"];
NSError *error=nil;
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithContentsofURL:getURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%",str);
```

This prints to the log the three values from my php as expected.

However I am having a little difficulty saving this in an array which then displays it those values in a `UISplitviewController` (the leftcontroller side).

which is written like this

```
showArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentofURL:getURL];
```

then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is

```
cell.textLabel.text=[showArray object atIndex:indexPath.row];
```

A second thing i have tried is write myURL to an array and tried to initlize showArray with `ContentsofArray` like this

```
NSArray *retults=[NSArray arraywithContentsOFURL:getURL];
showArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:retults];
```

but THAT dont work
BUT if i say

```
showArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",nil];
```

One and two shows in my leftview controller....
Would love is someone could help me with this...Thank you

Comment: Data you are receiving is in which format json/xml or just comma seprated value string

Comment: can u print the data u r receiving

Comment: @Chandru [{"animal":"Monkey"},{"animal":"Snake"},{"animal":"Cow"}]

Comment: this is a json data, U have to do parsing, study about json parsing

Comment: no,no I will explain u soom

Comment: @Chandru what fomat does it have to be in JSON parers online only tell me what it is valid JSON..(Oh ok Thanks)

Comment: u have done web services perfectly, now wat u have to do is parse it to an array

Comment: check my answeer and update me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U  have done web services perfectly, now wat u have to do is parse it to an array
First download the SBJSON files in this link

```
https://github.com/stig/json-framework/
```

Then, copy them to your workspace.
Then, in the viewController add this

```
#import "SBJson.h"
```

Your JSON data contains values in the form of dictionary

SO, to parse them

```
 SBJsonParser * parser=[SBJsonParser new];
 NSDictionary * jsonData=(NSDictionary *)[parser objectWithString:outputData];
 NSArray * arr=(NSArray *)[NSDictionary objectForKey:@"animal"];
```

I think this will help

Comment: where you have outputData i used str since since i had written the json data too that var.

Comment: [{"animal":"Monkey"},{"animal":"Snake"},{"animal":"Cow"}], ehere it is stored

Comment: I think im missing files, symbol(s) not found for architecture i386, i dragged everythig from the class folder to my project and did the import

Comment: Where is the variable JsonData used? also im getting a second warning on NSDictinary on 3rd line

Comment: did u added the .m files in build phases-> compile sources

Comment: I had only added one, obviously i needed all, It runs but with a warning cause JsonData isnt used and another waring on NSDictionary ObjectForKey:@"animal"]; objectForKey isnt a method for that class.tried using dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"animal"nil but it also errored out

Comment: fine, did u got the concept how it worked, or else should i explain u

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47937/discussion-between-sleep-paralysis-and-chandru)

Comment: I get it, I also formatted my php and program so now I am getting animal: {animal  = monkey;} saved in The array, but so far nothing in my cell :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to add the contents of the URL or the URL itself ?

If you are trying to just add the URL, then use :

```
showArray = [@[getURL] mutableCopy];
```

However, if you are trying to add the contents of the URL, then [the doc clearly states](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithContentsOfURL%3a) that the URL must represent a string representation of an array.

Furthermore :

> Returns nil if the location can’t be opened or if the contents of the location can’t be parsed into an array.

**EDIT** :

I saw your comment on your post and your data looks like JSON data.
You should take a look at the `NSJSONSerialisation` class which is pretty straightforward to use (you'll find lots of example here on SO).

Comment: the doc says that string and array objects are accepted, my data returns as an array. so shouldnt my array be able to be initalized with the contents of said URL?

Comment: Yes it should. However, it is commonly used in combination with the method 'writeToURL:atomically:'. So your array pointed by the URL is surely not recognized by 'initWithContentsOfURL:'.